# Why is it possible to reassign `const x` in the console after an await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, google-chrome-devtools, constants

**EDIT:** I discovered you don't even need the function. This works too for me:

```js
const x = await 'hello'
x = 'something else'
```

*Note that without the `await` it throws an error.*

By first defining an async function,

```js
async function a() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve('hello')
  })
}
```

Then assigning `x` to `'hello'`,

```js
const x = await a()
```

Then reassigning `x`.

```js
x = 'something else'
```

If `x` is a constant variable, why can it be reassigned? Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Here's the complete code (tested in browser console on Chrome 80.0.3987.87):

```js
async function a() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve('hello')
  })
}

const x = await a()

x = 'something else'
```

Comment: You really haven't posted enough code to give an answer; a normal `const` symbol cannot be reassigned.

Comment: With your update, it looks like your question is about the quirks of the chrome developer console and top-level await. Normal code will not behave that way.

Comment: Looks almost like a bug of REPL along with top level await. Note: splitting the code in REPL, i can reproduce it on chrome and FF, but not on node (where top level await just throws an error, probably, because my node version is 12.10.0 and not the newest)

Comment: `const x = await 'hello'
x = 'something else'` 

this breaks me even more...  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce what you describe. It throws an error for me.

```js
async function a() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve('hello')
  })
}

(async () => {
  try {
    const x = await a();
    x = 'something else';
    console.log("worked", x);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("didn't work", err.toString());
  }
})()
```

With your updated question, i see that this occurs when you enter the code in the chrome developer console. Futhermore, your code is using await outside an async function. Top-level await is not yet a part of the javascript standard, though it is working its way [through the approval process](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await). The dev tools do let you do it, but i would not be surprised if the behavior that results is nonstandard.

Comment: The top-level-await proposal is for modules only, it won't have any effect on `await` in the devtools console.

Comment: True. Meaning i have even less of an idea what the dev tools do with it :)

Comment: Huh, interesting. I never knew about top-level await.

Answer (score 1):

> **Update:**  I'm able to reproduce the error in: Firefox 72.0.2 (64-bit), 
>   However if you wrap it within an `async` function it doesn't behave like that..

To know more about: [**ECMAScript proposal: Top-level await**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await#ecmascript-proposal-top-level-await)

> You can await strings because it's permitted: [block-await-expr-literal-string.js](https://github.com/leobalter/test262/blob/6952c3cabe8c867e7884dbcf2369bd1092adba6e/test/language/module-code/top-level-await/syntax/block-await-expr-literal-string.js),
>   AwaitExpression StringLiteral (Valid syntax for top level await in a
>   block.)
>   Thus `const x = await '';` is valid syntax

```
(async () => {
    async function a() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve('hello')
        })
    }

    const x = await a()

    x = 'something else'

})();
```

Hmm, probably you're missing the console debugger..

```
async function a() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve('hello')
  })
}

const x = await a()

x = 'something else'
x = 'not assignable... in console or whatever..';
```

[image: Type Error]

[image: Execution is paused..]

Comment: That's quite odd, I don't get any error on my console. https://i.imgur.com/aF7jTxJ.png

Comment: I can also reproduce when I enter the three snippets as separate statements, not all at once.

Comment: Also, it's enough to wrap it in a block (`{…}`) to trigger the exception

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using *await* keyword in sync function (your func here is the global scope).
It doesn't make sense. We are using *await* to wait for some async operation for ex. API call.

If you remove *await* it will normally throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please don't use browser console as an ideal editor environment when you are learning these things.

Secondly I just checked what you mentioned in the browser console.

If you simply copy and past your whole code once it gives an error as expected saying constants can't be reassigned. as clearly mentioned in the @some user's answer.

But if you copy and past it line by line it won't give you any errors.

I'm not exactly sure what is the reason but you can't expect browser console to provide you with 100% compiler/validation environment.

So unless it is some simple expression evaluation it is best to use a good development environment so you won't get confused by unexpected behaviors.

If you still need something that runs on the browser try this 
http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

**EDIT:** I found this comment on @Nicholas Tower's answer and it seems like the correct answer to this question

> "The top-level-await proposal is for modules only, it won't have any
>   effect on await in the devtools console. – Bergi"

Happy coding!!!